# What is the role of GC(Garbage Collection) other then memory management

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

What is the role of GC (Garbage Collection) other then memory management?

-Anil

Comment: How do you mean? The purpose of GC is memory management, it doesn't have another role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role of the Garbage Collector is just the memory management. It remove non-referenced objects from memory. Therefore memory management is made much easier.
In some rare cases memory leaks are still possible.

Answer (score 2):

Reducing bugs due to memory mis-management.

Comment: I don't think that the GC reduces bugs on itself. It makes memory management easier, but leaks (e.g. due to weak references) are still possible

Comment: The leaks are also easier to find. Because when you leak memory you can find from which GC-root the stuff is reachable. That makes it easy to find the code which produces the leak. The 'forgotten-to-free' leaks are harder to find the trace back.